# i am trying to add an image into another image...like say a piece of furniture into a picture of a room

Tags: print-design

I am trying to add an image into another image. As an example, a piece of furniture into a picture of a room.
I have a picture or image of a picture on a wall in a room, and I am wanting to add a sofa under the picture.

Comment: Hi Ken, Did you mistakenly hit "Submit" too soon and have more to add or was this it? You might want to click the [**EDIT**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/107552/edit) link under the question and add a whole lot more detail regarding the problems you may be having. As this stands, it's fairly difficult to understand what specifically you are asking or what, if any, problems you are experiencing.

Comment: I am asking how to "photoshop" another image into the original image.

Comment: The only way to ‘photoshop’ anything is to learn how to use Photoshop. Do that first and then come back here if you are struggling with a specific problem.

Comment: I've voted to close. This is not a "tutorial on demand" web site. You are essentially asking -- *"I have two piles of wood. How do I build a house?"* -- Do a bit of research using Google searches for combining images with Photoshop. You'll find hundreds of tutorials there.

Answer (score 1):

You clip out the piece you want to transfer and then place it on the new image.
There are many ways to do the clipping.

Furniture is easier than say hair.

The concepts are the same. You "select" the "area" you want to clip and then place it on a layer above your background image.

The clipping can be done with direct selection tool or magic wand tool, plus other ways. For the actual clipping process I recommend you study and practice methods from YouTube.

Clean clips are a useful technical skill.

Cutting and pasting the couch is the basic part. Blending the clip into the new image can be hard if the room you are putting it in is at a different angle or perspective than the couch image.

If they are both straight from the front than there is not a problem. If the picture of the room is at an angle than the couch pic must be at the exact same angle or close to it.

Your clip can be skewed slightly with warp and transform tools to be made to appear to fit in the room, but only slight warping is possible before it looks distorted.

The angle of the couch and the angle of the room must match before starting or there will be problems.

If you were placing a free floating clip into a background without much perspective reference, like a bird into a sky, there would not be the distortion problem.

Shading, lighting and blending of the 2 images can be accomplished with Photoshop effects, you should look up some of the common methods.

Answer (score 0):

The two images need to have some features in common.

- Similar perspective. Try to figure out if the two images are taken from similar heights, distance, and similar lenses.
- Illumination. If your furniture has strong shadows, because was taken next to a window with direct sunlight, and the interior is not, it would look fake.
- Good enough resolution to work with. A thumbnail of an image will not work if the other one is a High-quality image.

---

Then you need to:

- Mask the furniture.
- Cut and paste.
- Adjust the proportion, and adjust a bit the perspective.
- Adjust the colors, brightness, contrast, and saturation. "The feel"
- Ad shadows on the room where the furniture should have projected them in the first place.